# Div quebrando linha mesmo com White-Space: Nowrap

Tags: javascript, html, css

Anteriormente eu escrevia diretamente no TD o texto e não quebrava linha, mas necessitei que fosse escrito no JS, porém ao inserir no JS acontece a quebra de linha como na imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
HTML
    <th data-sortable="false" data-field="ID" data-switchable="false" data-card-visible="false" data-formatter="fe" class="acoes" style="white-space: nowrap;"></th>
```

---

```
JS
    $('.acoes').html('Preços | Alunos | Associar Vendedor | Desassociar Vendedor | Upload | Configuração');
```

P.s: Anteriormente não era passado o style="white-space: nowrap;" e funcionava normalmente, conforme deu esse problema adicionei para tentativa de resolução.

Comment: Testando aqui não houve quebra de linha.

Comment: aqui em todas as telas acontece a mesma coisa, e editando diretamente no F12, funciona do jeito que eu queria, não sei o que poderia ser feito

Comment: Posta a tabela completa e o CSS relacionado a ela na pergunta. Só assim dá pra analisar melhor e tentar reproduzir o problema. Pode ser que tenha outra coisa influenciando nisso.

Comment: A tabela é gerada automaticamente pelos dados vindo do BD

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido somente adicionando diretamente ao CSS externo o nowrap, pelo style nao envia os dados para a pagina